# Handle every request in Application_BeginRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

As title suggested, how can I achieve that in my webform project? Currently, if a url points towards a file, the server will send the response with that file without ever entering `Application_BeginRequest`. Even the `MapPageRoute` method does not change this behavior. Is there a simple solution?

Comment: Have you tried System.Web.HttpApplication.Application_AcquireRequestState?

This should fire before any file is transferred.

Comment: @CooncilWorker Does not work for me. Do I need to register the event handler somewhere? (Just curious although there is already a working solution.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wish to set this in your `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

So that even static files are processed by ASP.NET.